# compute an approximation of pi using cuda in python

Tags: python, gpu, pi

I would like to use this simple formula to compute an approximation of pi :
[pi approx formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FieyU.png)

Here is my code :

```
def pi(iteration):
    pi = 0.0
    sign = 1
    b = 1.0

    for i in range(iteration):
        pi += 4.0*sign/b

        b += 2
        sign *= -1

    print pi

pi(100000)
```

How to make this code be computed by the GPU?

Answer (score 0):

use this [PyCUDA](https://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda/) allows you to run code on GPU, here are [docs](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/)

But I must say is not a good idea just to mess around with it. Be careful of overheating.

also another alternative is this [PyGPU](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Calle_Lejdfors/pygpu/)

Comment: What's the worst that could happen?

Comment: with that particular code nothing serious, but as you play around with more dangerous toys you risk loosing your graphic's card :)

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any concrete example?

Comment: nope non :) also, another alternative that runs also on GPU is Theano library in Python http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Numba.
Here is a good example specifically for CUDA using python for calculating value of pi.
https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/examples/pi.py

Comment: This website page results as not accesable. Is there anyone similar?